# Hardcode or abstract views?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, data-binding

I'm developing a WPF app using MVVM where I show error messages/special dialogs via a lightbox styled pop-up. These sub-Views are User Controls displayed by a `ContentControl` in the main View.

Up until now, each sub-View has been hardcoded to perform a single function (say, display error or ask the user to backup first). But as the app progresses, I'm seeing the the same design pattern from most of these controls:

- Icon image in top left corner
- Heading text next to icon
- Message text in the middle
- 2 buttons in the bottom right corner

With MVVM I should be able to abstract this pattern and reuse this control for displaying errors, asking the user to back up, anything really, just by binding. I should even be able to bind the names of the buttons or even hide 1 if it isn't used...stuff like that.

But should I? Is there a performance benefit/hit from doing it like this? Seems like this would fall under DRY when there's 8 sub-views all with the same grid pattern.

Comment: Your feeling is correct. To have 8+ dialog controls where the only the difference is the message is awkward indeed. The basic interaction dialog boils down to show message and return a boolean as a result (`DialogResult` object). The simplest solution would be to create a `DialogWindow` which exposes e.g. icon and message properties that you set before showing. You can put messages into  a resource file. Icons go into a `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: The issue is not about performance, but maintainability. If you decide to change the look of the dialogs you would have to change it 8+ times. Reusing a control means saving time.

Comment: @BionicCode: Thank you for the detailed response. Ya, your first message was exactly what I was thinking of doing. But I didn't even think about it from a maintaining standpoint though, which makes your second response very compelling.

Answer (score 1):

Dry is not about performance.

It's about saving you time writing code and in the maintenance phase.

Whilst it would be more elegant to make one generic re-usable window this probably comes at some sort of cost.

Does the work cost you more than the benefit you get? The decision whether to rationalise into one probably-more-complicated view or not should be based on a sort of cost benefit analysis.

Factors you should consider:

How long does it take to make each view?

How complicated is the functionality in each?

How much effort is necessary to make a generic?

How many exceptional cases are there and how much would they complicate making this generic?

Would making this generic obscure functionality and to what extent is it going to make maintenance more expensive?

How likely is it you'll have to change the look of these things?

If you're highly unlikely to change the look, there are a few edge cases make a generic view complicated and injecting your functionality has complications then just copying and pasting markup into each view makes some sense.

Edit:

Remember that styling is re-usable.

Here's a concrete bit of markup to consider.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Path Data="{Binding IconGeometry}"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Fill="Black"
              Height="28"
              Width="28"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Heading}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding Message}"/>
        <ItemsControl 
            Grid.Row="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding NamedCommandCollection}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

You present a viewmodel to this.

This viewmodel implements inotifypropertychanged and provides a string property for the heading, message etc.

The less-obvious things here are a path with a geometry rather than image. This depends on what your iconography will look like exactly but the simple one colour shape is very common now.

You can define geometries in a resource dictionary, grab the appropriate one out of there and supply it as a property. Merged resource dictionaries go in application.current.resources which is pretty much an in memory dictionary of objects keyed by a string of your x:key.

The buttons are produced by an itemscontrol which templates out it's items into a horizontal line of buttons.
Build a viewmodel representing a button.

string property for name and a relaycommand or delegatecommand for the ButtonCommand.

Let's call that a ButtonVM.

Add a ButtonVM to an observablecollection property NamedCommandCollection and you get a button appears. Add one, two, three. However many you like.
You could make the ButtonVM just take a relaycommand you build and supply or have one itself and you inject an action.  You can capture variables as you build an action dynamically.

Command also has canexecute. You can use that to refine when a button can be clicked or not. EG I have a property IsBusy in a base viewmodel which I use to flag whether any command is "running" to obviate that very fast double click breaking everything.

Here it is:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isBusy;
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => isBusy;
        set => ToVal(ref isBusy, value, nameof(IsBusy));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public void ToObj<T>(ref T backer, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        backer = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
    public void ToVal<T>(ref T backer, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(backer, value))
        {
            return;
        }
        backer = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return;
    }
}
```

Icommand has a canexecute bool and will disable a control a command is bound to if it's false. However, this relies on commandmanager deciding to requery canexecute and disable that control. There are circumstances when this won't happen fast enough. Hence it's best to use the bool to guard the code in a command.

A fairly random example out some real code:

```
    private RelayCommand newMapCommand;

    public RelayCommand NewMapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return newMapCommand
            ?? (newMapCommand = new RelayCommand(
              () =>
             {
                 if (IsBusy)
                 {
                     return;
                 }
                 ResetMap();
                 IsBusy = false;
             },
             ( ) => !IsBusy
             ));

        }
    }
```

Relaycommand is in mvvmlight. Since I work in net core nowadays and there's a dependency in commandwpf on net old, I grabbed the source for the bits I want of mvvmlight. I retain the namespaces since Laurent will probably eventually address this or net 5 may obviate the issue.

A usercontrol can itself contain a usercontrol.  If you wanted flexibility then it could have a contentcontrol and template out what is bound to it's content.

This is used for viewmodel first, a common way to switch out content for navigation etc. I wrote an example to explain the evils of pages :^) 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this excellent response! It's these sorts of questions, while tough on their own, become especially hard when you are still learning a framework. I'm thinking it would be extremely easy to make this generic, but also, I can see it also obscuring functionality. For instance, the buttons become Left and Right buttons but in the ViewModel they are 'Backup' and 'Upgrade'. But then like BionicCode says, maintenance becomes much more expensive when they are separate, and I've only really applied basic styling so far!

Comment: I added some markup and more explanation of possibilities.

Comment: Wow Andy, thank you for spending more time on this! The XAML is basically what I did (even the icons are svgs in a ResD) but the observable collection to allow any number of buttons is brilliant. I ran into a problem with this as I got going, the solution I came up with was to bind visibility of a button to it's name: if null, not visible. Another problem I ran into was while I use the same outer shell, I do have a few differences like 1 has a header only and the other also has a subheader. I'm wondering, can we have have 3 layers in the UI (i.e. Page -> UserCntl -> User Cntl)?

Comment: And your IsBusy intrigues me because I think I have experienced bugs from a fast doubleclick. The implementation is just a bit over my head, how do I use it?

Comment: Andy, thank you so much. Great info here that will help me a lot.